# case statement with group by in jpa named query giving syntax error?

Tags: group-by, case, openjpa, named-query

We are getting syntax error in group by clause while using group by with case statement in JPA named queries. We are using openjpa. Query looks like this(ids is a list in mentioned query)

select r.city,case when r.name='test' then 'T' else 'N' end as opt from testable r where r.id in (:ids) group by r.city,case when r.name='test' then 'T' else 'N' end

Comment: Show the error, and you might want to simplify things while trying them out; if you know the :IDS works, create a simple query that doesn't need to filter on the list so we/you can focus on the group by logic. Or try the query without the group by etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
String jpqlQueryString = "select  r.city,"
+ " case when r.name='test' then 'T' else 'N' end as opt "
+ " from testable r "
+ " group by r.city, opt";
```

This should work, and then you can add in criteria to filter on.

Comment: We have tried above query, it is showing query is invalid, your select and having clauses must only include aggregates or values that appear in your grouping clause. I guess alias name for case statement causing issue.